# Allow React front-end (with ssl certificate self-signed) to make calls to C# API back-end

Tags: c#, reactjs, api, deployment

I have devloped a project (an online store) using React for the front-end and a C# API with SLQ extention for the back-end.

Everything works fine with http and https on localhost using Swagger, however if I try other apps like Insmonia i get this message if i use GET method on "https://localhost/producto": Error: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK

I didn't realize until I deployed the web site on a Debian 11 virtual machine using a self-signed SSL certificate and the calls to the API were getting this error: (failed) err_connection_refused

I have the next Program.cs file.

```
using ApiProyecto.Models;
using ApiProyecto.Services;
using ApiProyecto.Helpers;
using Base.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Net;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(opt =>

{

    opt.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;

});


builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>

{

    options.ValueCountLimit = 2147483647;

});
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
{
    builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>

    {

        var jsonInputFormatter = options.InputFormatters.OfType<SystemTextJsonInputFormatter>().First();

        jsonInputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("multipart/form-data");

    })
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();


// configure strongly typed settings object
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProductoService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ContactoService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<PedidoService>();



// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSqlite<BaseDeDatos>("Data Source=tiendadb.db");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BaseDeDatos>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("BaseDeDatos")));


builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
{
    options.Preload = true;
    options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
    options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(60);
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("example.com");
    options.ExcludedHosts.Add("www.example.com");
});



builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});


var app = builder.Build();

app.CreateDbIfNotExists();




// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
}
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
//cors
app.UseCors("AllowAll");

app.UseHsts();

app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And here is an example of the front-end calls (process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL is the url where I deployed the API)

```
export function getProducto(dispatch) {
  fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"/producto").then((result) => {
    result.json().then((resp) => {
      dispatch(todos_productos(resp));
    });
  });
}
```

How can I allow https calls from the front-end to the back-end?

I have tried apps like Postman, Insomnia, Swagger, tried many sample codes and done a lot of research and found almost nothing but 3 lines of code that don't work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the self-signed certificate you are using. The cross-origin request is refused due to the certificate being untrusted. You can get a free signed certificate from services such as Let's Encrypt and then you should be able to fetch your api from your frontend application. If you want to keep using your self signed certificate for testing purposes you can try to declare it as trusted manually from your browser or directly from you operative system.